# adding symbols to an string variable during the program

Tags: string, scheme

I am new to Scheme and I am trying to write a program that in each step adds a symbol to a string and at the end returns the string.
For example making a string like "TFTFT..."

```
(define str "")
(define foo
        (lambda (x)
            (
              (if(eqv? (car x) 3) (string-append str "T") (string-append str "F"))
              (if(eqv? (car (cdr x)) 4) (string-append str "T") (string-append str "F"))
              (if(eqv? (cdr (cdr x)) 5) (string-append str "T") (string-append str "F"))
            )))
```

I want the results as below:

```
> (foo '(3 4 5))
"TTT"
> (foo '(3 6 5))
"TFT"
```

I know that the string-append part is not correct. Would you please help me about it?

Also, when I try to run the program an error comes up:
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: "T"
  arguments...:
   "F"
   "F"

Comment: hm, for one thing `(cdr (cdr x))` will return a list.  You want `(car (cdr (cdr x)))` for the element `5`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not write it carefully. I just designed it to point out my problem which is how to "append some symbols to a string" during the recursion.
for example:
initila value : str = ""    ;
next recurion : str = "0"   ;
next recurion : str = "01"  ;
next recurion : str = "011"   ;
next recurion : str = "0110"   ;
...and then gives this string as an output.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> making a string like "TFTFT..."

which sounds like you're trying to do this for any length of input sequence, not just a list of 3 numbers.  The rule for choosing T vs. F to append to the string *seems* to be whether the list element is one greater than the preceding list element.  Is all this correct?

If that's what you're trying to do, you need to do this recursively rather than trying to test all elements in the same go by writing more if-clauses.  Try something like this:

```
;; foo-rec: list-of-ints  string  int -> string
;; Returns a sequence of TFT... values indicating whether the corresponding nth position in 
;; the input list myseq contains the value (expected_val + n - 1).
(define (foo-rec myseq mystr expected_val)
  (cond 
    [(empty? myseq) mystr]
    [(= (car myseq) expected_val) (foo-rec (cdr myseq) (string-append mystr "T") (add1 expected_val))]
    [else (foo-rec (cdr myseq) (string-append mystr "F") (add1 expected_val))]))
```

which gives

```
> (foo-rec '(3 4 5) "" 3)
"TTT"
> (foo-rec '(3 6 5) "" 3)
"TFT"
> (foo-rec '(3) "" 3)
"T"
> (foo-rec empty "" 3)
""
> (foo-rec '(3 4 5 7 7 8) "" 3)
"TTTFTT"
```

For more on recursion, take a look at the ["How to Design Programs" (HTDP)](http://htdp.org/2001-11-21/Book/node54.htm#9896) (or [its headier brother, SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1)).  The former makes for very light reading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I think I can not pass any other input to the function foo as a string.
Can I do that in another way?